# How to use service inside another?

Tags: angular, typescript, oop, angular8

I have service that performs requests to server:

```
export class ExportDictionaryApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  public perform(): Observable<any> {}
}
```

There is another class factory:

```
export class ExportFactory {
  public static createConcreteExcel(type: string) {
    switch (type) {
      case EReferenciesTypes.DictionaryType:
        return new ExportDictionary();
    }
  }
}
```

And concrete class that is returned by factory:

```
export class ExportDictionary implements IExport {
  export(parameters: any) {
     this.apiService
      .perform().subscribe((response: IResponseDict) => {});
  }
}
```

**Using is:**

```
ExportFactory.createConcreteExcel('full').export([...parameters]);
```

**Problem is:**

Concrete class should use concrete `apiService`, and now there is no ready object `apiService` inside `class ExportDictionary`

How to pass it in concrete class?
I need return ready instance with all dependencies inside!

Certainly I can inject ready object in method:

```
ExportFactory.createConcreteExcel('full').export([...parameters], injectedApiService);
```

But I dont know `injctedApiService` uNtil I dont create concrete Factory.

Also I can not create object inside:

```
export(parameters: any) {
       new ExportDictionaryApiService()
          .perform().subscribe((response: IResponseDict) => {});
 }
```

Because `ExportDictionaryApiService` requires dependency `HttpClient`

Comment: Seems you need to use @Injectable for `ExportFactory`, then Angular appy dependencies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-factory

p.s you can change the string to enum

Explanation

You need a factory as below

```
@Injectable()
export class ExportFactoryService {

 constructor(
    @Inject('Export') private services: Array<IExport>
  ) { }

  create(type: string): IExport {
    return this.services.find(s => s.getType() === type);
  }

}
```

an interface for your service

```
export interface IExport {
   getType(): string; // this can be enum as well

   export(parameters: any):any;
}
```

and your service implementation, I implemented two services

```
@Injectable()
export class ExportDictionaryService implements IExport {

  constructor() { }

  getType(): string {
    return 'dictionary';
  }

  export(parameters: any):any {
    console.log('ExportDictionaryService.export')
  }

}
```

and most important part, provide multiple services in app.module

```
  providers: [

    ExportFactoryService,
    { provide: 'Export', useClass: ExportDictionaryService, multi: true },
    { provide: 'Export', useClass: ExportJsonService, multi: true }
  ]
```

and this is how you get an instance of your service

```
  constructor(private exportFactoryService: ExportFactoryService) {}

  create() {
    const exporter = this.exportFactoryService.create('dictionary');
    exporter.export('full');
  }
```

and this approach is Open-Closed, you can extent it by adding new services, and you don't need to modify existing codes, and there is not if/else, or switch/case statement , no static class, and it's unit testable, you can inject whatever is needed in each exporter services

Comment: Thank you, but how to inject http to `export class ExportDictionaryService` ? to use it in export method?

Comment: like the other services in the constructor of the class you want to use, just remeber, your ExportDictionaryApiService  needs to have @Injectable and should be provided in a module